# How to find all functions $f$ such that $f(f(m)+n)+f(m)=f(n)+f(3m)+2014$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$f(f(m)+n)+f(m)=f(n)+f(3m)+2014$$

for every $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm completely stuck after trying to plug different things into the above functional equation. I would like to know a complete solution to this problem please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: why do you want to prove such a thing? Will it be helpful for your work?

Comment: Put $m=0$, then you get $f(n+f(0))=f(n)+2014$.

Comment: @CalvinLin No, the $f(0)$'s cancel out once the substitution is made.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ah yes. Too early in the morning lol. Thanks!

Comment: @nozalp10 it is very helpful if you can help me to solve it

Answer (score 4):

Much of what we see is just smoke and mirrors.

Any functional equation looks simple once it is solved. So I'd rather put the answer before the solution: $$f(x)=2x+1007$$
Now the boring part.

1. As noted by **Samuel Adrian Antz**,
   $$f(n+C)=f(n)+2014,\text{ where }C=f(0)\tag1$$
   By applying this repeatedly, we may also find $f(n+2C),\;f(n+3C)$ and so on.
2. We have many things inside $f$ and very few things outside $f$, which is a sure sign that we need injectivity. Indeed, $f$ is injective. The proof is rather involved (read: on an entirely different level of "boring"), so feel free to skip directly to step 9.
3. Suppose there are some $k_1\ne k_2$ such that $f(k_1)=f(k_2)$. Then plug them instead of $m$:
   $$
   f(f(k_1)+n)+f(k_1)=f(n)+\color{red}{f(3k_1)}+2014\\
   f(f(k_2)+n)+f(k_2)=f(n)+\color{red}{f(3k_2)}+2014
   $$
   Everything except the red term in both equations is the same, so the red terms must also be the same. So if we have one pair of arguments giving the same values of $f$, then we may have another such pair by tripling them.
4. Now plug $k_1,\,k_2$ instead of $n$:
   $$
   \color{red}{f(f(m)+k_1)}+f(m)=f(k_1)+f(3m)+2014\\
   \color{red}{f(f(m)+k_2)}+f(m)=f(k_2)+f(3m)+2014
   $$
   By the same reasoning concerning the red term, now we may produce another such pair by *shifting* $k_1,\,k_2$ simultaneously by the value of $f$ anywhere, for example, by $C$ (which is its value at $0$).
5. Whatever our $C$ might be, there are some powers of $3$ such that $C$ divides $3^a-3^b$.
6. By tripling, produce the following identities:
   $$f(3^ak_1)=f(3^ak_2)\tag2$$
   $$f(3^bk_1)=f(3^bk_2)\tag3$$
7. Now let's do some shifting. As I said before, $3^a-3^b$ is a multiple of $C$. So is $(3^a-3^b)k_1$. Well, let's shift **(3)** by that much:
   $$f(3^ak_1)=f(3^bk_2+(3^a-3^b)k_1)\tag4$$
8. By combining **(2)** and **(4)**, we now have:
   $$f(3^ak_2)=f(3^bk_2+(3^a-3^b)k_1)$$
   But wait, now the difference of arguments is $(3^a-3^b)(k_2-k_1)$, which is a multiple of $C$, so by repeated application of **(1)**, they must differ by quite a number of $2014$'s, instead of being equal. A contradiction.
9. Now we know that from $f(k_1)=f(k_2)$ follows $k_1=k_2$, which immediately makes a lot of things a lot simpler. Plug $m=n$:
   $$f(f(n)+n) = f(3n)+2014 \stackrel{by\;(1)}{=\!=\!=} f(3n+C)\\
   f(n)+n=3n+C\\
   f(n)=2n+C$$
10. Now $f(C)=3C$, but also $f(C)=f(0+C)=f(0)+2014=C+2014$, so $C=1007$.

So it goes.

Comment: In the steps 5,6,7,8 Can you explain to me C divides 3^a-3^b

Comment: There are infinitely many powers of 3, but only so many different remainders modulo C, so some powers must have the same remainder, so their difference is divisible by C.

Comment: In the steps 7,8 I didn't understand what you did

Comment: If $f(k_1)=f(k_2)$, then $f(k_1+C)=f(k_2+C)$; do we agree on that? Any pair can be shifted by C, or by 2C, or my any integer multiple of C. That's what I did.

Comment: Thanks but in 7 how you make it like this $f(3^ak_1)=f(3^bk_2+(3^a-3^b)k_1)\tag4$

Comment: Why, we just take the pair from the equation (3) and shift it by a certain amount.

Comment: Thank you for your answers